# How to create staircase with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm learning Python and one of my assignments was to create the following staircase, using user input for how many stairs:

```
How many stairs? 6
#####
#####
##########
##########
###############
###############
####################
####################
#########################
#########################
##############################
##############################
```

So far this is what I have:

```
stairs = int(input("How many stairs? "))
for i in range(1,stairs+1):
    print("#####",end="")
    for j in range(1,i):
        print("#####",end="")
    print()
```

This gives me

```
#####
##########
###############
####################
#########################
##############################
```

But how do I create a second line identical from the one above? I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: if only there was a way to call these `print` statements twice every time... oh wait:)

Comment: Hey man I'm trying to learn here...

Comment: I don't think that was meant as an insult or something

Comment: Hey man, they're trying to teach you here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do like,

```
>>> stairs = 6
>>> for i in range(1, stairs+1):
...      print("#####" * i)
...      print("#####" * i)
... 
#####
#####
##########
##########
###############
###############
####################
####################
#########################
#########################
##############################
##############################
```

Comment: I prefer the explicit 2-print version (as the Zen of Python says: "explicit is better than implicit")

Comment: yep, and it was more didactic

Comment: Okay. Changed it back :) Thanks

Comment: @hansolo , perfect!

Comment: @Don Readabilty matters, i should remember :)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner (little bit, not to much) version, with two print statements, could be:

```
n = int(input("How many stairs? "))
stair = '#####'

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(stair * i)
    print(stair * i)
```

Comment: one stair is 5 (five) sharps =)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
stairs = int(input("How many stairs? "))
for i in range(stairs):
    print("#" * (5*(i+1)))
    print("#" * (5*(i+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The funny unreadable one-liner:

```py
list(map(print, ("#####" * i + "\n" + "#####" * i for i in range(1, int(input("How many stairs?")) + 1))))
```

Comment: Nice one, but it could have been a comment.

Comment: I still think it answers the question